# Calculating the network of co-occurrent terms in text mining

Tags: r, text-mining

I'm new to R and I'm working on some text analysis for multiple pdf files.
So far I have managed to plot the wordcloud and the bar chart. However, I also need to make the co-occurrence graph or as called Network analysis or links graph. Can anyone help me with some guidance on how to apply that to my current code and what library should I utilize?
Here is the code:

```
require(pdftools)# reads pdf documents
require(tm)#text mining analysis
require(wordcloud)
require(RColorBrewer)

files<-list.files(pattern = "pdf$")#create vector of pdf file names (i included the pdf files in the same foldr)

alcohol<-lapply(files, pdf_text) #loads all the files

length(alcohol)# check the number of files

lapply(alcohol, length) #check the length of each file


pdfdatabase <- Corpus(URISource(files), readerControl = list(reader = readPDF)) #crearing a pdf database 
pdfdatabase <- tm_map(pdfdatabase, removeWords, stopwords("english")) 
pdfdatabase <- tm_map(pdfdatabase, removeNumbers) 
alcohol.tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(pdfdatabase, control = list(removePunctuation = TRUE,
                                                              stopwords = TRUE,
                                                              tolower = TRUE,
                                                              streaming = FALSE,
                                                              removeNumbers = TRUE,
                                                              bounds = list(global = c(3, Inf))))



ft <- findFreqTerms(alcohol.tdm, lowfreq = 20, highfreq = Inf)

as.matrix(alcohol.tdm[ft,])

ft.tdm <- as.matrix(alcohol.tdm[ft,])
sort(apply(ft.tdm, 1, sum), decreasing = TRUE)



#find frequent terms
findFreqTerms(alcohol.tdm, lowfreq = 10)
#Examine frequent terms and their association
findAssocs(alcohol.tdm, terms = "sensor", corlimit = 0.5)




#convert term document matrix to data frame
m <- as.matrix(alcohol.tdm)
v <- sort(rowSums(m),decreasing = TRUE)
d <- data.frame(word = names(v), freq=v)


#create wrodcloud
set.seed(1234)
wordcloud(words = d$word, freq = d$freq, min.freq = 10,
          max.words = 200, random.order = FALSE, rot.per = 0.35,
          colors = brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))



#Create Bar chart
barplot(d[1:11,]$freq, las = 2, names.arg = d[1:11,]$word,
        col = "lightblue", main = "Most frequent words",
        ylab = "Word freqencies")
```

Thanks in advance

[a screen shot from the console after running the object ft.tdm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vScMj.jpg)

Comment: Please note the RStudio tag, is reserved for questions related to the IDE itself, not to the R programming language. Please read the tag description before selection. In the case of RStudio: it states “DO NOT use this tag for general R programming problems, just use the R tag. ONLY use for RStudio-specific questions”.

Comment: Do you care about how often a word appears in a particular pdf (e.g. tf/idf) or is co-occurrence just a binary term e.g. found or not in a pdf?

Comment: Furthermore, we need example data of the obejct `ft.tdm` e.g. using function `dput`

Comment: I don't care about how often the word appears in a particular pdf; however, I care about how often it appeared across all the documents I included. Basically, i'm studying several published articles related to one topic

Comment: I just attached an example of the ft.tdm object in the main question. I just took a screenshot of the console after running the ft.tdm

Comment: We need the output text of `dput(head(ft.tdm, 10))`. Screenshots are useless, because we can not copy them into our R session.

Comment: The output is too long to be here in the comment  so I copied it to a doc in google drive 
here is the link: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mrwrqORYY-QCggJt8sIye5JL7wD63MGsduzDpAeuY-I/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can start with a simple Chi-Square test to test if there are lots of documents having both terms and lots of documents lacking both terms. This test can be applied to all pairs of terms:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(ggraph)

# Ignore how many hits per document
ft.tdm.binary <-
  ft.tdm %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  mutate_all(~ ifelse(.x > 0, 1, 0)) %>%
  as.matrix()

co_occurrences <-
  ft.tdm %>%
  rownames() %>%
  combn(2) %>%
  t() %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  rename(from = V1, to = V2) %>%
  mutate(
    test = list(from, to) %>% pmap(~ chisq.test(ft.tdm.binary[..1,], ft.tdm.binary[..2,]) %>% tidy())
  ) %>%
  unnest(test)

co_occurrences
#> # A tibble: 45 x 6
#>    from    to        statistic p.value parameter method                         
#>    <chr>   <chr>         <dbl>   <dbl>     <int> <chr>                          
#>  1 “alcoh… “just      2.05e-31   1             1 Pearson's Chi-squared test wit…
#>  2 “alcoh… “the       1.65e+ 0   0.199         1 Pearson's Chi-squared test wit…
#>  3 “alcoh… <U+FB01>…  1.23e-30   1.00          1 Pearson's Chi-squared test wit…
#>  4 “alcoh… <U+FB01>…  1.12e+ 0   0.290         1 Pearson's Chi-squared test wit…
#>  5 “alcoh… <U+FB01>…  4.47e- 1   0.504         1 Pearson's Chi-squared test wit…
#>  6 “alcoh… <U+FB01>…  2.07e- 1   0.649         1 Pearson's Chi-squared test wit…
#>  7 “alcoh… <U+FB01>…  4.66e- 4   0.983         1 Pearson's Chi-squared test wit…
#>  8 “alcoh… <U+FB01>…  1.56e- 1   0.692         1 Pearson's Chi-squared test wit…
#>  9 “alcoh… <U+FB01>…  4.47e- 1   0.504         1 Pearson's Chi-squared test wit…
#> 10 “just   “the       4.85e-30   1.00          1 Pearson's Chi-squared test wit…
#> # … with 35 more rows


co_occurrences %>%
  mutate(effect_size = sqrt(statistic / ncol(ft.tdm))) %>%
  # only show the significant co-occurrences
  filter(p.value < 0.05) %>%
  ggraph() +
    geom_node_label(aes(label = name)) +
    geom_edge_link(aes(color = effect_size))
```

[image]

Keep in mind that it does not really mean much if there are lots of documents in which both terms are lacking.
This is especially true for rare occurring words.
In this case, one might want to use the Jaccard test instead.

This is a general statistical method not tailored to any other properties of text documents.

Comment: I used your code right below my code and I keep getting this error: Error in mutate(., effect_size = sqrt(statistic/ncol(ft.tdm))) : 
  object 'co_occurrences' not found

Comment: You need to run the whole code including the lines creating `co_occurrences`

Comment: I did run the whole code